# TCL: open a file and return a list of non-empty lines with comments and blank lines stripped

Tags: tcl

I have some old perl code that opens a file that contains a list of files and returns the files as a list. further this list of files can have blank lines and comments to make the file list more readable, but these are stripped from the final list returned by the procedure  See the example below.  How would I covert this into a TCL procedure?

```
# PERL VERSION
sub load_file_list() {
    my $file_list = shift;

    print "load_file_list: $file_list\n";

    my @ret   = ();

    open(F, "$file_list") || die("could not open file: $file_list\n");
    while(<F>) {
        my $line = $_;

        $line =~ s/\r//g;           # remove CR
        chomp($line);               # remove LF
        $line =~ s/\/\/.*$//;       # remove '//' comments
        $line =~ s/#.*$//;          # remove '#' comments
        next if ($line =~ /^\s*$/); # remove blank lines

        while($line =~ /\$(\w+)\b/) {
            my $avar = $1;
            $line =~ s/\$${avar}\b/${${avar}}/g;
            #print "$line\n";
            push(@ret, $line);
        }       
    }
    close(F);

    return @ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proc load_file_list { file_list } {

    puts "load_file_list: $file_list"

    set ret {}

    set err [catch { 
        set fp [open "$file_list" r]
        set file_data [read $fp]
        close $fp   
    }]

    if {$err} {
        puts "ERROR: could not open file: $file_list"
        return $ret
    }

    set data [split $file_data "\n"]
    foreach line $data {
        # remove comments       
        regsub -all -line "#.*$" $line "" line

        # remove leading and trailing white spaces
        set line [string trim $line]

        if {$line eq ""} {continue}

        #puts "$line"       
        lappend ret $line
    }

    return $ret
}

set flist [load_file_list "ducks.syn.txt"]

foreach f $flist {
    puts "=> $f"
}
```

Comment: You should provide for some explanation along with the snippet, to help future readers to appreciate the key steps in rewriting the Perl script as a Tcl script.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a 1:1 translation

```
proc load_file_list {file_list} {

    # I don't like hardcoding the proc name
    set procname [lindex [info level 0] 0]

    puts "$procname: $file_list"

    set ret {}

    try {
        set fh [open $file_list]
    } on error e {
        error "coult not open file $file_list: $e"
    }

    while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {

        set line [regsub -all {\r} $line ""]            # remove CR
        # no need to chomp, gets removes the newline
        set line [regsub {//.*} $line ""]               # remove // comments
        set line [regsub {#.*} $line ""]                # remove # comments
        if {[string trim $line] eq ""} then continue    # remove blank lines

        # expand variables in the line
        # executing in the calling scope, presumably the variables are in scope there
        set line [uplevel 1 [list subst -nocommands -nobackslashes $line]]
        lappend ret $line
    }
    close $fh

    return $ret
}
```

Comment: You don't generally need to convert an `or die` at all; Tcl's builtins throw exceptions quite well enough by default. Also, CR removal is done by default in the channel.